# TextBlock style overwrites Templated parent style

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

Firstly, I have a style as a resource in application resources, like so:

```
<Style x:Key="ContentTextBlock" TargetType="FrameworkElement">
   <Setter Property="TextBlock.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
   <Setter Property="TextBlock.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
   <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontFamily" Value="Verdana"/>
   <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="12"/>
   <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
   <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Orange"/>
</Style>
```

I have created a custom control that has a header, and content in it.
This is how the Content section looks like in the custom control template:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                  Style="{DynamicResource ContentTextBlock}">
</ContentPresenter>
```

My problem is that if I use the created control like so:

```
<local:CutPage.Content>
            <TextBlock>Header</TextBlock>
</local:CutPage.Content>
```

the Fontsize, FontWeight and FontFamily get overriden by TextBlock's explicit or default style(I think that is the case, but i am not sure). I have read the articles about dependebcy value order od precedence, but how can I guess what is overriding my template style? I want all header elements that get into the custom control to use these values. How should I do that?

P.S. the interesting thing is that some of the style setters work(like centering the text vertically and horizontally) but others dont!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your CustomControl, you'll have to define Dependency Properties matching the textblock properties, and do a Binding in your ControlTemplate.

What I would do would be to create a CustomControl which derive from TextBox, then change it's ControlTemplate to add what you need and bind everything you need int he ControlTemplate.

Alternatively, you could just use **HeaderedContentControl** that seems to do exactly what you need.

```
<HeaderedContentControl FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="Red" Header="Hello World">
    <Rectangle Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Blue" />
</HeaderedContentControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you put your base style in a separate file and than use it inherit from it in your textblock, sth like this:

```
<TextBlock>
<Style TargetType="..." BasedOn="{StaticResource MyGeneralStyle}">                       <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="..."/>
</Style>
</TextBlock>
```